# Drawing sprites and bitmaps in Java OpenGl (JOGL)

Tags: java, graphics, sprite, jogl

I'm creating a tile based RPG and I would like to render tiles and character sprites. What would be an easy and efficient way of drawing and rendering bitmaps in JOGL?

Comment: Rather ask this question on the official JogAmp forum if you look for a JOGL specific answer. There are several ways to do that, texture atlas, mesh instancing, ...